# Eigenvalues of discrete second order derivative

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am trying to calculate the eigenvalues of the discrete second order derivative, with both Neumann and mixed Dirichlet-Neumann boundary conditions. I'm following the derivation here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors_of_the_second_derivative#Neumann_case
But there are some things I don't understand for each derivation.

**Neumann boundary conditions**

For a grid of $n$ points, the problem corresponds to finding the eigenvalues of the $n\times n$ matrix

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{h^2}\,
         \begin{pmatrix}
     -1 & 1 & & &  0\\
     1 & -2 & 1 & &  \\
      & 1 & \ddots & \ddots & \\
     & & \ddots & \ddots & 1 \\
     0 &&  & 1 & -1
     \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

where $h$ is the grid spacing, which I will set to be unity. Unfortunately, there are a few things I don't understand. They define $\vec{v}$ to be the eigenvector corresponding to an eigenvalue $\lambda$. They state that the eigenvalue problem corresponds to solving the problem

$$
v_{k+1} - 2v_k + v_{k-1} = \lambda v_k \quad \Rightarrow \quad v_{k+1} = \left(\lambda+2\right) v_k - v_{k-1}
$$

This is true, but not for all $k$ and it bugs me that this is not stated. Is this not important? Instead of working with $v_k$, they work with $w_k$, which is defined

$$
w_k = v_{k+1} - v_k \quad \Rightarrow \quad w_k- w_{k-1} = v_{k+1} - 2v_k + v_{k-1}
$$

This can be used to find a recursive expression for the $w$'s.

$$
w_{k+1} =(2+\lambda) w_k - w_{k-1} = 2\alpha w_k - w_{k-1}
$$

They then state that the boundary conditions are $w_0 = w_n = 0$. *But why?* $w_0 = v_1 - v_0 = v_1$ and $w_n = v_{n+1} - v_n = -v_n$. I don't see why either of these should be zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The eigenvalue equation $v_{k+1} - 2v_k + v_{k-1} = \lambda v_k$ is actually true for all $k$. I think your confusion is in the introduction of the dummy variables $v_0$ and $v_{n+1}$ and in your mixing the Neumann and Dirichlet boundary conditions.

The variables $v_{0}$ and $v_{n+1}$ are introduced specifically to ensure that $v_{k+1} - 2v_k + v_{k-1} = \lambda v_k$ is true for all $k$, but they have different values for the Neumann and Dirichlet conditions:
$$ \text{Neumann condition:} \quad v_0 = v_1 \quad v_{n+1} = v_n.$$
$$ \text{Dirichlet condition:} \quad v_0 = 0 \quad v_{n+1} = 0.$$
What you wrote in your calculation of $w_0 = v_1 - v_0$ and $w_n = v_{n+1} - v_n$ was a combination of these two mutually exclusive conditions which is why you obtained the contradiction $w_0 = v_1 - v_0 = v_1 = 0$ and the analogous one for $w_n$.

Comment: Ah okay, I think I understand. The variables $v_0 = v_1$ and $v_{n+1} = v_n$ are introduced, so $v_0-v_1$ and $v_{n+1} - v_{n}$ can be added to the l.h.s. of the equations
$$
-v_1 + v_2 = \lambda v_1
$$
and 
$$
v_{n-1} -v_n = \lambda v_n
$$
Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. That's one way to see it. Alternatively, they are there so that you only have a single eigenvalue equation for all rows of the matrix.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much! 

Comment: Is there an analytic expression / equation for the eigenvalues (or eigenvectors) like this, in 2D or 3D (for Neumann)?  The derivation in the Wikipedia page seems to just be for 1D, and the extension to 2D/3D does not seem to be trivial...

Comment: It depends on the form of the higher dimensional finite difference equation and the associated boundary conditions. For example, if the finite difference equations in each extra dimension is independent of the the equations in other dimensions, then you can solve them independently and just get multiple copies of the one-dimensional solution