# Eigenvalues of discrete second order derivative w/ Dirichlet-Neumann boundary conditions

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am trying to figure out the eigenvalues of the discrete second-order derivative operator, but I am having trouble figuring out the Dirichlet-Neumann boundary conditions. I asked a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3959563/eigenvalues-of-discrete-second-order-derivative) regarding pure Neumann boundary conditions the other day, and someone was graceful enough to help me. I am following the derivation done here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors_of_the_second_derivative#Dirichlet-Neumann_Case. The eigenvalue problem can be represented by the matrix

\begin{equation}
    T = 
         \begin{pmatrix}
     -1 & 1 & & &  0\\
     1 & -2 & 1 & & \\
      & 1 & \ddots & \ddots & \\
     & & \ddots & \ddots & 1 \\
     0 & &  & 1 & -2
     \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

The point is to find the eigenvalues, by comparing the recurrence the eigenvalue problem gives for the elements of the eigenvectors, $v_k$, to the recurrence that defines Chebyshev polynomials. There are a few places in the derivation where I get a bit confused.

The problem is solving the equation

$$
v_{k+1} - 2v_k + v_{k-1} = \lambda v_k
$$

which is valid for all $k$ by introducing the dummy variable $v_0 = v_1$. The next step is to introduce auxiliary variables $v_{j+0.5} = v_{j+1} - v_j$, and they state a recurrence relation

$$
v_{j+0.5} = 2\beta v_j - v_{j-0.5}
$$

for some $\beta$. This recurrence relation can be rewritten

\begin{equation}\tag{1}
v_{j+1} = (4\beta^2-2)v_j - v_{j-1}
\end{equation}

I understand that the $k^\mathrm{th}$ Chebysev polynomial of the second kind can be related to the $(k+2)^\mathrm{th}$ and $(k-2)^\mathrm{th}$ polynomials by

\begin{equation}\tag{2}
U_{k+2}(x) = (4x^2 - 2)U_k(x) - U_{k-2} (x)
\end{equation}

which has the same form as the above given relation, except the Chebyshev polynomials are separated by two orders, whereas the relation for the auxiliary variables are only separated by one order (hope this phrasing makes sense).

After stating the recurrence relation for the $v_j$'s, they compare it to the one the eigenvalue problem gives, and the new recurrence relation solves the problem when $4\beta^2 - 2 = 2+\lambda$. So far, I understand it, but then they spring this on me: "Our new recurrence gives

$$
v_{n+1} = U_{2n+1}(\beta), \,\,\, v_n = U_{2n-1}(\beta)
$$
"
which I unfortunately just don't understand. My best bet is the following: with the introduction of dummy variables, $v_j$ is defined for $j = 0,1/2,1,...,n+1$, i.e. in steps of $\Delta j = 1/2$. If we "normalise" this to $\Delta j = 1$, then the recurrence in (1) is actually comparable to the recurrence in (2). However, this is not a very convincing argument to me (at least I haven't been able to find a way to phrase it convincingly). Is my thinking correct, or am I right to doubt it? I will be extremely grateful for an input.